# Common user login for two different wordpress installation and bbpress

Tags: multisite, user-access, bbpress

I have situation, that i need common user login for

1. Blog A
2. Blog B
3. bbPress

I found the solution Single use login for two wordpress installation from Justin Tadlock Blog.

[Installing two WordPress blogs with the same users](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2008/09/20/installing-two-wordpress-blogs-with-the-same-users)

But What for bbPress ?

Is there any plugin can work for me ?
Should i use wordpress multisite (i am using it)?

Thanks In Advance !

Comment: Voted to close as a 'shopping question'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Multisite User Management](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/multisite-user-management/installation/)

This plugin works for me!
Automatically add users to each site in your WordPress network.

Comment: You never mentioned you were already on WordPress multisite? This plugin doesn't work for separate individual WordPress installs, only Multisite installs hence 'network'

Comment: You can see the question "Is there any plugin can work for me ? Should i use wordpress multisite (i am using it)?" Also tag

Comment: @TomJNowell BTW sorry if i made any mistake, thanks for all

Comment: But no plugin is necessary, multisite gives you a single userbase shared across sites. If this is simply a 'give me a plugin' question then I'm sorry but I'll have to close vote this. Shopping questions are not in the spirit of this QA site

Comment: No, If this can be done by without plugin then its grate for me. What  I want to do is if i register in "Blog A" then i will able to login in "Blog B & 
bbPress" automatically. Is that possible ? how ? In my multisite installation I am not able to do this

Comment: If it's a domain based install you need to login for each site, but you can use the same user+pass as its the same user. If its a subfolder based install you don't

Answer (score 1):

You should have used WordPress multisite, so a single install running 3 separate sites, one for Blog A, one for Blog B, one for BBPress. You should also be using the BBPress v2 plugin, not the standalone BBPress v1

Comment: WP multisite work for all platform without any customization, am i right ?

Comment: Multisite works where single site works, PHP Mysql....